# delphi integrate custom file editor into IDE

Tags: delphi, ide, integration

I have deveoped a custom file type, together with a custom editor (basically a tree with several data pages attached and a few extra buttons). OK, I can run it stand alone and that is fine, and even add it to the tools menu, but I would like to integrate it into the Delphi IDE so that my custom editor (or a similar new version) appears in the IDE, rather like a DFM file has a custom editor. I can find references to most extensions in the Delphi IDE, but not this one. Any guiding hands? Note that this is not a property or component editor (the file type has nothing to do with either of these) nor is it simply syntax highlighting of a text file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it currently isn't possible to reliably integrate a custom editor into the Delphi IDE. The required API simply isn't there. See [QC89028 Custom Module support](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=89028).

During the Delphi 2010 and XE betas I spent most my spare time trying to get a resource editor integrated. Although the effort had the official blessing of Embarcadero and got some, half hearted, support from the IDE engineer, I was never able to get them to deliver on their promises and surface the module API. I eventually abandoned the project.

**Update:** I've now checked my old correspondence regarding this and it turns out part of the problem was that `IOTAModuleCreator` (used to implement File|New for custom file types) and `IOTAEditorContent` (used to transfer data to/from the custom module) only supports text data. Binary data gets mangled.

Comment: Interesting. See my answer which implies (though I've never done it) it is possible to make a custom view. I don't know how to associate it with a  file type though. Did you try something along these lines, and find you needed more exposed by the IDE?

Comment: The API only enables one to register a custom module handler (a handler for a custom file type) and to read the module data. The API does not provide any way to write the data back from the editor. So a custom module viewer is possible, but not a module editor. That said, as your answer correctly states, it _is_ possible to create a custom view, so if one doesn't mind that the data can't be saved through the normal IDE mechanism, then it's kinda possible. The editor won't really be integrated though. It will appear more as if it is a stand-alone application that has been docked inside the IDE.

Comment: This is all very exciting. My custom file type is plain text so that is not a problem, and I do only need one editor for a file type. I do need to save the data, but not through the IDE. It is not classically streamed or derived from TPersistent. As far as it being a stand-alone application docked within the IDE, I am not sure. Surely clicking on the file in the project manager will bring up the editor? If so, that is all I need. The 'wizard' generates two files within the IDE and modifies two more, so I will have to work out how to notify Delphi properly, but it all sounds doable.

Comment: I still have some source lying around that demonstrates a basic implementation of custom file type and editor integration. If you like I can mail it to you.

Comment: Got it. I'll prepare the source and mail it to you asap. I suggest you delete your comment to protect your email address.

Answer (score 1):

You can *probably* do this via an IDE plugin that uses the ToolsAPI (see ToolsAPI.pas in the IDE's source folder (e.g. `Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\source\ToolsAPI\ToolsAPI.pas`.)

For information on writing a plugin in general, see [David G Hoyle's excellent blog](http://www.davidghoyle.co.uk/WordPress/?cat=3). Once you know the basics - i.e., write a 'wizard' and get it to do something - you will need to work on integrating your editor.

I have never done this, and so I can't guarantee it is possible. However, some interfaces that look worth investigating and implementing are `INTACustomEditorView`, which represents a 'view' (file tab when that file is open - think the code editor, Welcome view, type library editor, etc) and `IOTAEditorViewServices`, to register your custom view.  I do not know how you associate a view type with a file type, sorry - possibly something to do with the personality interfaces. You might also be interested in `INTACustomEditorSubView` which is what creates a tab on the bottom of a file.

Good luck, and if you find a solution please write here so that other people can learn too!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have been using Marco Cantu's excellent book and created several property and component editors, yes and indeed I have created the wizard which works great as far as it goes. I have even added it to the menu system, but it is not tightly integrated into the system because I cannot really add the file reference I need automatically. I did consider creating a component that just hold the file name and create a component editor, but the result would not be as nice.

Comment: It looks (from the other answer here) like it would work if your custom file type is text. You could add your editor as a subview.  Would that be enough?

Comment: Hi David. I am not sure what you mean by a subview? Do you mean a tab (like code, design, history) in the main editor? If so, yes, that is exactly what I need. I don't need the text as a subview but I don't mind if it is there. I will always edit via the tree editor.

Comment: @Dsm Yes - `INTACustomEditorSubView ` should let you create a tab on the bottom of a file, like the Code / Design / History tabs. So if your file type is text, you could have the Code tab (i.e. normal default IDE behaviour, where someone can edit it as text) and then add a 'My Editor' tab that contains your editor. (Btw, if this answer is useful to you, can you upvote it please?)

Comment: I would love to upvote. I have tried twice (once when I saw the answers and just now) but it gets rejected. Apparently I do not have enough reputation. Sorry. I have been looking through ToolsAPI.pas, and it looks as if I should be able to do what I want, but whether I do it through a module (not well documented but looks like what I need) or a wizard (much better documented but not really geared towards what I am trying to do) is still an open question. I am inclined to try both on the grounds that one is more likely to succeed but the other would work better if I can get it to work.

Comment: @DavidM Have +1 on me. I too think your answer deserves it.